# How many wars have there been in Europe since WW2?

Tags: war

As far as I know, there has been:

- [Yugoslavian War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yugoslav_Wars)
- [War between Albanians and Serbs about Kosovo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosovo_War)
- [NATO bombing of Serbia and Montenegro (which could be included above)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_bombing_of_Yugoslavia)
- And currently Russian-Ukrainian war

Beside those, has there been more on European soil?

**Note :** Some say that war between Russia and Ukraine started back in 2014, whatever the case, I'd count that as one, combined with the ongoing situation.

War = A state of armed conflict between different countries or different groups within a country.

Comment: How are you defining "in Europe"? Do both sides of the conflict need to be on the European continential shelf or just one, or does fighting need to be on the continential shelf?

Comment: @Puffafish well the I'm curious about the war which took place in European soil as I mentioned above. I don't care about intervention of some countries in the other part of the world, because looking on things that way, US had like 15 wars, but none of them in their country, so my question isn't about that.

Comment: As a side note, there has been a "State of War" (*Stan Wojenny*) in Poland in ~1980's. While this is was not a war declared on a particular country, and the Wikipedi name is *Martial Law*, the translation of the the Polish name is *State of War* (as in being in that state)

Comment: @WoJ That is more of a translation question between languages: in Hungarian, it is also phrased similarly, but it doesn't mean it is a real war.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Twenty six**

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pax_Europaea#List_of_wars) wikipedia article there have been twenty six wars in Europe during the period of Pax Europaea. Below is a list of them.

- Greek Civil War (Greece, 1946–1949)
- Northern Ireland Conflict, (1960s–1998)
- Basque conflict (1959–2011)
- Cyprus Emergency, (Greek Cypriots (EOKA) vs. United Kingdom, 1955–1959)
- Soviet invasion of Hungary (Soviet Union vs. Hungary, 1956)
- Invasion of Czechoslovakia (Soviet Union vs. Czechoslovakia, 1968)
- Turkish invasion of Cyprus (Cyprus vs. Turkey, 1974)
- Yugoslav Wars, 1991–2001

  - Ten-Day War (Slovenia vs. Yugoslavia, 1991)
  - Croatian War of Independence (Croatia vs. Yugoslavia, 1991–1995)
  - Bosnian War (Bosnia vs. Yugoslavia, 1992–1995)
  - Kosovo War (Kosovo vs. Yugoslavia, 1998–1999)
  - Insurgency in the Preševo Valley (UÇPMB vs. Yugoslavia, 1999–2001)
  - 2001 insurgency in the Republic of North Macedonia (National Liberation Army vs. North Macedonia, 2001)
- Georgian Civil War (Georgia, 1991–1993)
- East Prigorodny Conflict (Ingush militia vs. Russia, 1992)
- War of Transnistria (Transnistria vs. Moldova, 1992)
- Chechen–Russian conflict

  - First Chechen War (1994–1996)
  - War of Dagestan (1999)
  - Second Chechen War (1999–2000)
- Albanian Rebellion of 1997 (Albania, 1997)
- Russo-Georgian War (Georgia vs. Russia, 2008)
- 2014 pro-Russian conflict in Ukraine

  - 2014 Crimean crisis
  - War in Donbass
  - 2014 Russian military intervention in Ukraine
- Kumanovo clashes (National Liberation Army vs. North Macedonia, 2015)
- 2022 Russian invasion of Ukraine

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135233/discussion-on-answer-by-john-strachan-how-many-wars-have-there-been-in-europe-si).

Comment: "Basque conflict (1959–2011)" - was this actually a war?

Comment: It's a huge stretch to call either the "Basque conflict" or the "Northern Ireland conflict" a war.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Here is a timeline I recently made of conflicts after the WWII in Europe including Russian involvement. Size is according to deaths. Color, according to nature of the conflict. The **Bosnian War was harsh (95k deaths)**, but much so the **Greek Civil War (190k deaths)**. Also worth mentioning the **2nd Chechen war (75k deaths)**. The **Czechoslovakia Invasion (300 deaths)** pales in comparizon to the little known **Baltic Resistance (35k deaths)** to soviets, and also to the **Spanish Maquis (6,5k deaths)** is neglected often.

The majority of these conflicts are on the periphery of Europe. In fact, Western Europe only has had some minor conflicts. In addition, many of the conflicts were part of the [Cold War](https://www.historytimeline.com/list/cold-war/).

We could debate the frontiers of Europe and add colonial conflicts and international interventions, but I think this is not the point. The Russo-Georgian war was very much an European war, but decolonization wars were not. In fact, what you see is that Russia is involved in many, many of the conflicts in Europe. What's more important, **Russia seems to be involved in European conflicts non-stop**, excluding the latter Soviet years when they were unable to do much except for Afghanistan.

Comment: @alamar You mean that the Russian was basically kicked out with huge losses (>10000 Gruz 200) compared to Americans, who just withdrew after an agreement with the Taliban and had very small losses?

Comment: "after an agreement with the Taliban" хитрый план Байдена - who prevented the USA to have an agreement with Taliban in 2001 and not go there at all?

Comment: @alamar Plan Trumpa, it was his agreement. The invasion was to eliminate Al-Kaida and that was hardly doable in any other way and succeeded. The CCCP wanted to hold the communist regime and failed miserably.

Comment: The USSR created a secular Afghani state which would survive past the collapse of USSR and will only fail in 1993 I believe. Whereas the American backed Afghan state collapsed after what, two weeks?

Comment: @alamar It does not matter how long the collapse took, after Trump decided to Vietnamize the conflict, it was clear it must end up like South Vietnam.  It was a political decision. But the US military achieved what they wanted. Without those 14000 dead of the USSR soldiers (coalition losses about 3500 in 20 years).

Comment: It's very putinesque when you declare that you have achieved precisely what you wanted before blasting off.

Comment: @alamar The whole point in the beginning was to go after Al-Queda, there was never enough work or serious effort put into establishing a government that could survive without the occupation.  It was never something the government was committed enough to seriously trying (assuming it could even work).  Also a few years isn’t really that much more impressive than a few weeks when it comes to government lifespans.

Comment: And getting that point through took 20 years and $2 trillion?

Comment: Why is this even answered here? My question is not about how many wars did Russia/USSR had?

Comment: As per your question, this timeline contains all the major conflicts in Europe since WWII, many of which happen to have Russia involved.